# Cannot install Watir on Jruby 9.1.12.0 - Windows 7

Tags: windows, jruby, watir

I am trying to install gems from a  local gem repository into Jruby 9.1.12.0 and I am getting stuck on Watir which is pretty much the first one I tried.

I am running on Windows 7 with JDK 1.8.0_131

I get the following:

```
Error installing watir:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension
```

it looks as though the rest of the error message is complaining about ffi-1.9.18 I am afraid I can't post the exact error message as it is inside a VM that is not internet enabled.

update: full error message:

```
C:\Ruby\gem>jruby -S gem install watir
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
C:/jruby-9.1.12.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:58:  warning: Tempfile#unlink or delete called on open file
; ignoring
ERROR:  Error installing watir:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:       C:/jruby-9.1.12.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/ffi-1.9.18/ext/ffi_c
C:/jruby-9.1.12.0/bin/jruby.exe -r ./siteconf20170718-2540-6mqxiv.rb extconf.rb

current directory:      C:/jruby-9.1.12.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/ffi-1.9.18/ext/ffi_c
make "DESTDIR=" clean
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

current directory:  C:/jruby-9.1.12.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/ffi-1.9.18/ext/ffi_c
make "DESTDIR="
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

make failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in   C:/jruby-9.1.12.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/ffi-1.9.18 for inspection.
Results logged to  C:/jruby-9.1.12.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/extensions/universal-  java-1.8/2.3.0/ffi-1.9.18/gem_make.out
```

Comment: Good first attempt for a self answered question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working now. It was obvious from the error message that 'Make' was not being located correctly. I added the correct directory to the path and Watir was installed correctly.